# Shooting game - a probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> In a shooting game, the probability for Jack to hit a target is 0.6.
>   Suppose he makes 8 shots, find the probabilities that he can hit the
>   target in more than 5 shots.

I find this question in an exercise and do not know how to solve it. I have tried my best but my answer is different from the one in the answer key. Can anyone suggest a clear solution to it?

My trial: (0.6^6)(0.4^2)+(0.6^7)(0.4)+0.6^8

But it is wrong...

(The answer is 0.3154, which is correct to 4 significant figures)

Comment: To a few more, it is $0.31539456$. Luckily short binomial distribution calculation. Note that "more than $5$" means $6$ or $7$ or $8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of shots is n=8 and the probability of a 'successful' shot is p=0.6. This is the Binomial distribution.

The tail probability of a binomial distribution B(n,p) $X$, i.e. $P(X\geq x)$ is

$$\sum_{r\geq x}\binom n r (1-p)^{n-r}(p)^r$$

here your x is 6, n is 8, p=0.6, go figure...

EDIT: Okay you don't know what a binomial distribution is. Fine.

So you want 6 or more shots, that is 6,7 or 8.

How many ways can you have exactly 8 out of 8? well exactly 1 way. 
What is the probability of this? $0.6^8$

How many ways can you have exactly 7 out of 8? well, you can miss 1 of the 8. 
What is the probabilty of missing 1 out of 8? $0.4\times 0.6^7$
so it is $8\times 0.4\times 0.6^7$

How many ways can you have exactly 6 out of 8? well, you can miss 2 of the 8.
This is not so easy. The formula for missing x out of n is $\binom n x$

This means $\dfrac{n\times(n-1)...\times 1}{[x\times (x-1)....1][(n-x)\times(n-x-1)...1]}$

In this case this is  $\dfrac{8\times7...\times 1}{[6\times5... \times 1][2\times 1]}=\dfrac{8\times 7}{2\times 1}=28$

So there are 28 ways you can exactly miss 2 out of 8. The probability of each miss is $(0.6)^6\times 0.4^2$

Putting these all together, we have $0.6^8+8\times 0.6^7\times0.4+28\times (0.6)^6\times 0.4^2$ whatever that is.

If this still doesn't make sense, you should look at binomial distribution.

Comment: Are there easier ways? I don't know binomial distributions :(

Comment: @redcap okay, let me edit this...

Comment: @Lost1, the formula is $\sum \binom nrp^r(1-p)^{n-r}$, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks!

Comment: @Lost1 Thank you very much, you make it clear!

Comment: @redcap NP, if nothing else, you need to know the 'choose x from y formula' I have given above here. binomial distribution is merely the distribution you get from picking x things from y things.

Comment: @redcap thanks for changing the 7 to a 6 :P

Answer (score 2):

Using [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), the required probability will be $$\sum_{6\le r\le 8}\binom 8r(0.6)^r(1-0.6)^{8-r}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this problem:

1. Find the probability asked for or ...
2. Find the probability of what you don't want and subtract it from $1$. Since the problem has $8$ trials and is asking for more than $5$ trials being a successful hit, we only have to count the probabilities that Jack hit the target $6, 7$, or $8$ times. This is much easier than counting the probabilities that Jack can hit the target $1, 2, 3, 4, or 5$ times because this will take longer. Therefore, path $(1)$ is the way to go.

$(1)$ Finding the probability of hitting the target more than 5 times is very easy, as you have already completed half the job. Your answer:$$(0.6^6)(0.4^2)+(0.6^7)(0.4)+0.6^8$$ isn't necessarily incorrect, but it's just *not enough*. $$(0.6^6)(0.4^2)$$ is just showing that Jack his the target exactly 6 times and missed the other two times. But if we had a total of 8 shots, how do we know which 6 shots he made and which 2 shots he missed? Therefore you must multiply $(0.6^6)(0.4^2)$ by $8 \choose 2$, which is 56. Similarly, $$(0.6^7)(0.4)$$ is Jack making exactly 7 shots. So you must multiply this probability by $8 \choose 1$, which is 8. And lastly, $$0.6^8$$ is Jack hitting the target 8 times, never missing once. So we multiply this probability by $8 \choose 0$, which is 1.

Therefore our desired probability is just $$(0.6^6)(0.4^2){8 \choose 2}+(0.6^7)(0.4){8 \choose 2}+0.6^8{8 \choose 0} \approx 0.3154$$

**HINT:** Note that numbers I multiplied your probabilities with are the number of ways we can *arrange* the desired outcomes. For example, let Xs and Os denote Jack hitting and missing the target respectively. In how many ways can we arrange $$XXXXXOO$$, which is just the probability that Jack hits the target 6 times, and misses twice. This is $$\begin{align}
\frac{8!}{2!6!} & = {8 \choose 2} \end{align}
$$
Use this to figure out the respective probabilities: That Jack makes no more than 5 shots, than Jack makes exactly 3 shots, that Jack makes exactly $m$ shots, where $m$ is a positive integer such that $0\le m\le 8$. And all of the scenarios require that Jack only has 8 shots.

Comment: I added some details to [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/117938/242) to the question you put a bounty on. Hopefully this makes the method clearer.

Comment: It does thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Total shots = n =  8

Success = p = The probability for Jack to hit a target is 0.6

Failure $= q = (1-p) =$ The probability for Jack to NOT Hit a target is $(1- 0.6) = 0.4$

P( He can hit the target in more than 5 shots, i.e. from 6 to 8 ) $= [ P(X = 6) + P(X = 7) + P(X = 8) ] =$   $
 [\binom{8}{6}.(.6)^{6}.(.4)^{8-6} + \binom{8}{7}.(.6)^{7}.(.4)^{8-7} + \binom{8}{8}.(.6)^{8}.(.4)^{8-8} ]$